# Wallet Connect: The requested account and/or method has not been authorized by the user

Tags: web3js, metamask, react, walletconnect

I am using the exactly same wallet on both `Wallet Connect (Chrome) + MetaMask (mobile)` and `MetaMask (Chrome)` in calling a mint function of my smart contract. With `MetaMask (Chrome)`, the process goes smoothly; but with `Wallet Connect (Chrome) + MetaMask (mobile)`, this error occurs:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: The requested account and/or method has not been authorized by the user.
```

I am simply use

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  contractAddress
);

contract.methods.mintBatch(something).send({from: walletId, value: value}, (err, res) => callback(err, res));
```

with both `Wallet Connect (Chrome) + MetaMask (mobile)` and `MetaMask (Chrome)`. Does it require additional set-up for Wallet Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to use the following to replace the usual web3 to make it work:

```
const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID, // Required
});

walletConnectWeb3 = new Web3(provider as any);

contractSubstitute = new walletConnectWeb3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

contractSubstitute.methods.mintBatch(something).send({from: walletId, value: value}, (err, res) => callback(err, res));
```

The web3 has to be walletConnect web3.